# Is it possible to query an integer range within a string field?

Tags: mysql

Say I have a simple mysql table containing a name field which is just a varchar.  The name field contains a string of the following format.  "channelname,unix_timestamp,unix_timestamp". e.g. "bbc1,123456789,123456889".  I need to select all rows, where a channelname matches, and where a given timestamp falls within the range of the 2 timestamps.  For example, given the timestamp 123456800, and the channelname 'bbc1' The above record should be selected.

How I would accomplish this is to first select all records with "name like 'bbc1,%' split out the two timestamp fields in the calling code, and filter the results there to those containing the given timestamp.  Is there a better, more efficient way.  My DB could have a very large number of records which match "name like 'bbc1,%'", and it's only expected to grow as time goes on.

I unfortunately don't have the ability to alter the table to add the two timestamp fields, the only thing I have to go on is that single name field. It's also possible that the name field may contain some arbitrary string not of the given format for some records, however all records which start with the given channel name should match this format.

Comment: you'd have to split the string, cast as int  and then do a comparison on the results

Comment: Why do you can't alter the table to add the two timestamp fields? This is *exactly* the solution of your problem. Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form.

Comment: The reason I can't modify the DB schema is that my code does not own the database, it's an existing DB from a different product.  The records already exist in the database in that form,  I just need to be able to select from the records.  I was hoping for a more efficient solution than just select all and process the results outside of the db, but if that's not possible, it's not possible, and I may have to introduce caching or something like that in software as opposed to pre-filtering at the DB layer.